# How to show that there is no embedding or immersion of a torus into a $S^2$?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

How to use transversality for the embedding and covering spaces for immersion?

Comment: This isn't really an appropriate level for MO, but here's a hint: the result is more general. If $M$ is compact, $\dim M = \dim N$, and $f: M \to N$ is an immersion, it is necessarily a diffeomorphism. This may help you see what pieces to think about.

Comment: @mme Your comment is almost right, but not quite. The conclusion is that $f$ would have to be a covering space.

Comment: @DannyRuberman Thanks for correcting -- I wrote too quickly.

Comment: @mme Thank you so much. I understand your argument, but is there a way to use the argument of transversality to prove not an embedding and covering spaces to prove not an immersion?

Comment: Transversality is irrelevant here. To prove that there is no embedding observe that the image will be both closed and open, hence your embedding would be a homeomorphism. Now use whatever algebraic topology tools you have (or, say, Jordan curve theorem) to reach a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, immersion implies that this is a local homeomorphism, and since the torus is compact, it is a covering. For coverings $X\to Y$ we have the [Riemann-Hurwitz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Hurwitz_formula):
$$\chi(X)=d\chi(Y),$$
where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic, and $d\geq 1$ is the degree of the covering. Since $\chi(T)=0$ and $\chi(S)=2$, this is impossible.